# python Attributes error

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

i just want to ask, what's wrong with my codes, or am i missing something. because when i call the function PausePlay() in the PlayAndPause() I always get an error saying:

```
  self.dbusIfaceKey.Action(dbus.Int32("16"))
  AttributeError: 'OpenOMX' object has no attribute 'dbusIfaceKey'
```

Here's the code:

```
  OPTIONS = 'omxplayer -o local -t on --align center --win "0 0 {1} {2}" \"{0}\"'
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
  from PyQt4.QtGui import *
  from Tkinter import *
  import sys
  import os
  from os import system
  import dbus,time
  from subprocess import Popen
  try:
      _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
  except AttributeError:
      _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
  MoviePath = '/media/HP v250w/Our Story in 1 Minute.mp4'
  class OpenOMX(QtCore.QThread):
      def __init__(self):
          QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

      def run(self):
          global MoviePath
          global myctr

          width = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().width()
          height = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().height()      
          cmd = OPTIONS.format(MoviePath,width,height-60)
          Popen([cmd], shell=True)
          done,retry = 0,0
          while done==0:
              try:
                  with open('/tmp/omxplayerdbus', 'r+') as f:
                      omxplayerdbus = f.read().strip()
                  bus = dbus.bus.BusConnection(self.omxplayerdbus)
                  print 'connected'
                  object = bus.get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer','/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2', introspect=False)
                  self.dbusIfaceProp = dbus.Interface(object,'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
                  self.dbusIfaceKey = dbus.Interface(object,'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
                  done=1
              except:
                  retry+=1
                  if retry >= 50:
                      print 'ERROR'
                      raise SystemExit
      def PausePlay(self):
          self.dbusIfaceKey.Action(dbus.Int32('16'))

  class VidControls(QtGui.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
      def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
          'some codes here'
      def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
          self.btnPause.clicked.connect(self.PlayAndPause)
      def PlayAndPause(self):
          self.opn = OpenOMX()
          self.opn.PausePlay()

  if __name__=='__main__':
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      ex = VidControls()
      ex.show()
      play = OpenOMX()
      play.start()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any Comments or Suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The error tells you that the attribute `dbusIfaceKey` is not existing. This means that in the moment you call `PausePlay` the line `self.dbusIfaceKey = dbus.Interface(object,'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')` was never executed successfully. So did you call `run` before `PausePlay`? From the code you posted it seems that you never did. You should move those lines to `__init__` to make sure the variables are set.

Comment: Why are you importing Tkinter? You can't mix Tkinter and PyQt.